# C# Multiple strings in a if-statment

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm trying to check if a user input matches a few already known values. How do I do this in C#?

I've tried this:

```
if (UserInput.Text == "2", "4", "8", "16", "32")

      { do things 

      }
      else
      {
        do other things
      }
```

And a couple of other signs between my strings. Is it possible to check against all my strings or do I have to set up a seperate if-statment for all my strings?

Comment: Here's a hint:  make a `List` of your known values, and check if your list contains the input value.

Comment: No, you can't write that, perhaps you need to read something about the syntax of the if statement before going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `switch` to compare a string to multiple values:

```
switch (UserInput.Text) {
  case "2":
  case "4":
  case "8":
  case "16":
  case "32":
    // do things
    break;
  default:
    // do other things
    break;
}
```

You can put the strings in a hash set, and check if the hash set contains the user input:

```
HashSet<string> strings = new HashSet<string>();
strings.Add("2");
strings.Add("4");
strings.Add("8");
strings.Add("16");
strings.Add("32");

if (strings.Contains(UserInput.Text)) {
  // do things
} else {
  // do other things
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You could use an array:

```
string[] validValues = new string[] {"2", "4", "8", "16", "32"}
if (validValues.Contains( UserInput.Text))

  { do things 

  }
  else
  {
    do other things
  }
```

This way you get a nice, readable sollution.

Answer (score 2):

I like extensions methods for these situations

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int MatchWord(this string container, bool caseInsensitive, params string[] values)
    {
        int result = -1;
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (string s in values)
        {
            if (s != null && string.Compare(container, s, caseInsensitive) == 0)
            {
                result = counter;
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now you could write (whenever you need it)

```
int matchIndex = UserInput.Text.MatchWord(false, "2", "4", "8", "16", "32");
if(matchIndex != -1)
{
      // string is equal to one of the input
}
else
{

}
```

but you could also use this extension for

```
int matchIndex = UserInput.Text.MatchWord(true, "john", "ron", "mark", "james", "bob");
```

If you don't need the index of the matched word, you could simplify everything using a boolean for the return value of the extension method

Answer (score 0):

You could make an array of what you want to check against and just check if the array contains an elements that is the same as UserInput.Text.

Want a code example?

Answer (score 0):

I know the following solution is not good. But I am trying to do the same with If statement

```
if (UserInput.Text == "2"|| UserInput.Text =="4"||UserInput.Text == "16")

      { do things 

      }
      else
      {
        do other things
      }
```